# How can I center the text of a button

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to center the text of my button but it always is sticked to the right. I tried `gravity` and `textAlignment` but nothing works here is my code as follows:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Recipies" />
```

Comment: by default it is in center..show me your button image

Comment: I add this problem once, I just restarted Eclipse and it worked fine. Have you tried that ?

Comment: Reseting eclipse actually work, I think is some kind of bug or something. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this problem once, I just restarted Eclipse and it worked fine. Have you tried that ?